# How to solve Regex StackOverFlowError on very large value?

Tags: java, regex

I am using RegExp Jakarta 2.0.8 of Apache to validate values using the following regex:

```
^[\\w\\s!$()*,./:;=?@\\]\\[{}~\\-%]+$
```

Basically, it is not allowing Unicode or some special characters.
I am running a java code that performs this validation using this regex on a very large text and I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at org.apache.regexp.RE.matchNodes(RE.java:1376)
  at org.apache.regexp.RE.matchNodes(RE.java:1376)
  at org.apache.regexp.RE.matchNodes(RE.java:1376)
  at org.apache.regexp.RE.matchNodes(RE.java:1376)
  at org.apache.regexp.RE.matchNodes(RE.java:1376)
```

I think my regular expression is not efficiently written and causing for a loop in the check which leads to the stack overflow error.

The question is: is there a better way to write this regex?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to use Apache RegExp? There is no way around this, from what I see in the code. It implements a full recursive algorithm, so StackOverflowError is expected on long strings.

Comment: So what do you suggest? Should I use the java utils regex?

Comment: Yes. That is one option. The same regex should work without problem on long string. (Note that Jakarta project has been retired, so there will be no update).

Comment: Q: How long is the string in question?  Q: Could you show us the code where you're using the regex?

Comment: @paulsm4: I'm not OP, but I guess it's longer than 8k characters. I can reproduce the problem on my machine at that size. The problem can be temporarily alleviated by increasing the stack size, but it's not a safe solution.

Comment: Problem solved guys. I replaced my code to use the java utils regex and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Q: How big are some of these strings?

Comment: paulsm4, its about 2000 characters... although I already replace the Apache with java.util.regex. Works great. Also, the solution of Tagir worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that adding the reluctant specifier fixes your problem with Apache RE:

```
"^[\\w\\s!$()*,./:;=?@\\]\\[{}~\\-%]+?$"
```

Though I'd strongly recommend to use JDK standard regexps. It works even with your original regexp and in general works faster and supports more features.

Comment: `recommend to use JDK standard regexps ... in general works faster and supports more features.` It does support more features, but I have a bit of doubt about "works faster" in general.

Comment: @nhahtdh: well it depends on the usage patterns: for some regexps and some input strings Apache RE might be faster. Sometimes not. For example, seems that Apache RE does not implement Boyer-Moore for literals, but JDK surely does. Looking for substring `ABABABBBBABBABABABBABABBABABABBA` in the string of million random `A`/`B` chars is 4x faster by JDK (it's even faster than `String.indexOf`). Also Apache RE uses internally synchronized classes like `Vector` or `StringBuffer`. I did not perform thorough benchmarking, but I'm pretty sure that for common cases JDK performs well.

Comment: For the case of fixed string searching, JDK performs well, but using the regex in your answer, comparing with similar one on JDK (the JDK pattern is similar, but I change `+?` to `++`, or just `+`), Apache regex outperforms JDK by quite a bit on 64MB string.

Comment: It works too. Thanks to you I learned something about regex :) although I preferred to move on to java.utils.regex instead of Apache.